# How to make colored labels in feynMF/feynMP

Tags: color, labels, feynmf

There are several ways of adding a label to the vertex, e.g. as in code below.
It is documented how to make the colored polygons or lines, as done for the `V2`, but I couldn't find anything about making the label coloured.
Is it possible in the feynMP package?

```
\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,80)

\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}

\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,i2}
\fmf{fermion}{v2,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2}

% first vertex
\fmfdot{v1}
\fmflabel{V1}{v1}

% second vertex
\fmfv{d.sh=circle, d.fi=full, d.si=2thick, f=(1,,0,,0), l=V2}{v2}

\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

Result of the code: 
[image: feynman diagram with coloured vertex]

Comment: Did you try `\fmflabel{\textcolor{red}{V1}}{v1}`?

Comment: @Sigur great, it worked! Thanks you very much.
Put it into the answer so that I can accept it...

Comment: Nice! Let's wait for a more professional solution. I'm almost sure that it does exist.

Comment: How to move the position of labelling? What if I want it on other side of vertex or **fermion**?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comment.